# MSBuild target to print project references recursively

Tags: msbuild

I'd like to visualize the entire ProjectReference graph from a given project.
Something like `msbuild projA.vcxproj /t:ListProjectReferences`

and get something like:

```
projA.vcxproj -> projB.vcxproj, projC.vcxproj
projB.vcxproj -> projD.vcxproj
...
```

Any pointer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recursively Visiting Projects

If you have a hierarchy of project directories and you create a [`Directory.Build.targets` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022) in the root directory, the `Directory.Build.targets` file will be auto-imported by the projects.

A target defined in `Directory.Build.targets` will be available in each project. This target can use the [`MSBuild` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022) to call itself on other projects that are within the same directory hierarchy.

### ProjectReference

Within the context of a project, the [`ProjectReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#projectreference) item collection will be the set of all project references. A target defined in the project can use the `@(ProjectReference)` collection.

### Display Project References Recursively

A possible implementation of `ListProjectReferences`:

```xml
  <Target Name="ListProjectReferences">
    <Message Text="$(MSBuildProjectName) -> @(ProjectReference->'%(Filename)%(Extension)', ', ')" Importance="High" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference->'%(FullPath)')" Targets="ListProjectReferences" Condition="@(ProjectReference) != ''" />
  </Target>
```

**Notes**

- At `normal` verbosity MSBuild will output messages about each project. Run the command as `msbuild projA.vcxproj /t:ListProjectReferences /v:m` to eliminate that 'noise' from your report.
- Recursion stops when there are no project references. This is enforced by the `Condition="@(ProjectReference) != ''"` on the `MSBuild` task.
- The example implementation will report `projectname.ext ->` , i.e. nothing to the right of the 'arrow', for a project with no project references. If you prefer not to see this line, add `Condition="@(ProjectReference) != ''"` to the `Message` task.